# XPath XML namespace Issue

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have to read XML which has prefixes but namespaces are not defined

example

```
<department:employee xsi:schema="www.abcd.com abcd.xsd" >
<emp:name>
John
</emp:name>

</department:employee>
```

I am using Xpath in java

Is it possible to create dynamic namespace and bind it with document object

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a DOM API to read your input, you'll have to fix it first.

Regular expressions can help. Write a function that does the following:

- Read the file as text. Make sure you use the correct character encoding.
- Regex-search for `"xmlns:([^\\s:]+)="` to find all declared prefixes, store them in a Map.
- Regex-search for `"<([^\\s:]+):"`  to find all used namespace prefixes.
- Determine which prefixes are used, but not declared: For every used prefix find if it's in the Map.
- For each remaining prefix, replace the first `"[^\\s?-]>"` in the document with

  ```
  " xmlns:" + prefix + "='http://tempuri.org/" + prefix + "'$0"
  ```
- Try toad the resulting string into your DOM API, return the document.
- The namespace URI for `department` should now be `http://tempuri.org/department`, etc.

The regex patterns are approximations. The rules for allowed characters in XML namespace prefixes are [a bit more complicated than that](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Names). So `[^\s:]+` is not the real deal, but it might be good enough for your situation.